# Getting the length of an array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following code where I can't get the length of the array
The array size is defined in the unity inspector. The error is 
Error       `Item' does not contain a definition for`Length'

```
public class Item : System.Object
{
    public string name;
    public int Radius = 1;
    public GameObject obj;
}

public class Gen : MonoBehaviour {
    public Item[] Items;
    int iNum = Items.Length; // gives me an error
}
```

I feel like the issue is staring me in the face but it's one of those days ....

Comment: You must do `Items.Length` in a function

Comment: Whoever upvoting this post - please make sure code aligns with error message provided in the post.

Comment: @YotamSalmon You are wrong. You have to do `Items.Length` in a function or property function. This is an example of what I am talking about `public Item[] Items;
int iNum;

int getiNum() {
    iNum = Items.Length;
    return iNum;
}`  The only person who got this is Christos and Theo. Although,Christos   did not provide a clear answer. Please try to this in Unity before making further comment.

Comment: I can't think straight today, thanks guys !

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are assigning a field from a property of another field. Fields are initialized on construction. To get what you want, the length needs to be accessed from within a property or method like:

```
public class Item : System.Object
{
    public string name;
    public int Radius = 1;
    public GameObject obj;
}

public class Gen : MonoBehaviour {
    public Item[] Items;
    private int iNum { get { return Items.Length; /*add null check here to be safe*/ } } 
}
```

Comment: This describes what I said in my comment and is the right solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you declare a field initializer, using another field. You could get instantly that you want, by creating an object and then access get the length of the `Items`, anytime you want like below:

```
Items.Length
```

Comment: What does "creating an object" mean? This is the code that the OP already has in their question.

Answer (score 2):

You must initialise the array to use this function.

```
public Item[] Items = new Item[] { *ADD OBJECTS* };
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is how we initialize a `field`.

Quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx):

> Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields
>   outside a method. If you are trying to initialize a variable outside a
>   method, consider performing the initialization inside the class
>   constructor.

One way to go about with this is:

```
public class Gen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Item[] Items { get; set; } = new Item[] { };
    int iNum = -1;

    //Awake is called once by Unity since Gen inherits from  MonoBehaviour
    public void Awake()
    {
        iNum = Items.Length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how you even put the error message. Most people here think this is null error but OP said this is initialized/set from the Editor so I guess they missed that part. One problem with this code is that it's recommended not to use a constructor in a script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. It's long to explain here.

Comment: @Programmer very valuable input and correct way on how we should approach this. It would have been great if you proposed a direct solution to the OP and he/she would understand the `construction` stages. Really appreciate your edit and suggestions to this question.

Comment: In order to make things more clear - _**Awake() vs constructor**: if you work with class derived from MonoBehaviour, use Awake()._ [Reference](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/513464/view.html); Another [reference](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/862312/view.html) - _**Awake and Start**, **only happens** exactly when the application starts playing, and when things are instantiated in play mode. So to prevent stuff from leaking from the serialization process to the scene, avoid constructors._

Answer (score 0):

`public Item[] Items;` -- `Items` is null. You are declaring the variable (placeholder), but you are never setting it to a new array.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The question stipulates that the size of the Array is specified in the unity inspector which I assume to mean that it is being injected in IOC/DI

Comment: @Theo, true, but this can't be used until the value is injected.  If `Items.Length` were being accessed in an event, this would likely work.

Comment: Injected ? This is Unity3D(Game Engine) question not MSF Unity-Container?

Comment: No, not that Unity, this [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649564.aspx)

Comment: No, it's supposed to be Unity3D.  Unity3D (the game engine) has an 'Inspector' window that is similar to the Visual Studio 'Properties' window-- think of using the Properties window to set initial states for a Windows form or WPF form. In the case of Unity3D, the object instance should be created and then values are assigned after creating the instance.  Using one field to set another during instantiation is not possible here because the variable is not set to anything until after instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Items array variable an array. Your only defining a variable Items that holds an array of Item's, but actually holds nothing.

Also, you can't call `Items.Length` in class variable declarations. As Programmer has said, it must be done in a method or property. Since it is runtime code. So your Gen class minimally should look like:

```
public class Gen : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Item[] Items = new Item[] { }; // Now Items has an array
    int iNum;

    void Awake()
    {  
        iNum = Items.Length; // iNum will in this case will be zero, because the array is empty.
    }
}
```